# Selecting specific words in a string starting with and ending with specific characters, but different in-between

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract '`display2d...jpg`' in each string vector, but I am not sure how to do it efficiently. Is there a better way?

One way I did was to use the function, `str_extract()` like this.

```
l1 <- "<p><strong>Which piece can be rotated to match&nbsp;the display figure?</strong></p>\n\n<p><strong><img alt=\"\" src=\"/bundles/pppp/files/display2d_12-2.jpg\" style=\"width: 256px; height: 256px;\" /></strong></p>\n"
l2 <- "<p><strong>Which piece can be rotated to match&nbsp;the display figure?</strong></p>\n\n<p><strong><img alt=\"\" src=\"/bundles/pppp/files/display2d_8-2.jpg\" style=\"width: 256px; height: 256px;\" /></strong></p>\n" 
l3 <- c(l1,l2)

# grab everything in between display and jpg
inner <- str_extract(string = l3, pattern = "(?<=display).*(?=jpg)")

# then paste back display and jpg
paste0('display', inner, 'jpg')
```

Comment: Just `str_extract(string = l3, pattern = "display.*jpg")` or `str_extract(string = l3, pattern = "display.*?jpg")`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.